# How to add badge counter inside tabhost android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I need to show the number of notification inside a tab. How do i do that in android. My tab code looks something like this below.

```
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("HOME").setIndicator("HOME"),
            homepage.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("NOTIFICATIONS").setIndicator("NOTIFICATIONS"),
            notificationfragment.class, null);
    return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the tabhosts Spec by setting the view on it as-

```
 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("groups");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabwidget_tabs, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    spec.setIndicator(view);
```

Comment: what should be there in R.layout.tabwidget_tabs ?

Comment: This is the layout for tabItem.

Comment: View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        TextView tv_counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_counter);
        BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, tv_counter);
        badge.setText("6");
        badge.show();  This is the code i am having to show the badge in the tab. How do I update the badge from another class?